# Automapper: how to map a tuple of list of objects and enum to a list

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

For example i have the first object which is the source

```
class PersonEntity
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

and the destination is

```
class PersonDto
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

and an enum

```
enum NameMode
{
    first,
    full
}
```

my mapping profile create map looks something like this

```
CreateMap<(PersonEntity, NameMode), PersonDto>()
      .ForMemeber(dest => desat.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom<NameCustomeResolver>()));
```

where depending on the passed enum value i will either combine first and last name from the source or just use first name, now the issue is that i want to use this to map a list of PersonEntity to a list of PersonDto

i tried this

```
List<PersonEntity> source = new List<PersonEntity>();
List<PersonDto> destination = mapper.Map<List<PersonDto>>((source, NameMode.full));
```

i get the exception

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

after some research i tried the following

```
var result = source.AsQueryable().Select(p => (p, NameMode.full)).ProjectTo<PersonDto>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
```

but this one has the syntax error

> expression tree may not contain tuple literal

i just want to achieve mapping a list of PersonEntity to a list of PersonDto

Comment: You can try this: ``var destination = mapper.Map<List<PersonDto>>(source .Select(x => (x, NameMode.full)));``

Comment: @fbv that's it make it an answer so i can mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var destination = mapper.Map<List<PersonDto>>(source.Select(x => (x, NameMode.full)));
```

This works because `source.Select(x => (x, NameMode.full))` will create an enumerable of tuple `(PersonEntity, NameMode)`, since you already have a mapping configured between `(PersonEntity, NameMode)` and `PersonDto`. Automapper will automatically handle mapping between `IEnumerable<(PersonEntity, NameMode)>` and `IEnumerable<PersonDto>`.

Comment: please add the explanation for your answer.